# Prevent user from Sending Duplicate messages using PHP

Tags: php, spam-prevention

can anyone suggest a good PHP function, script, or method to Prevent user from Sending Duplicate messages?

Here's the scenario. I own a community website. Members can send each other messages. Then some spammers from Africa contacted all members by sending copy paste messages. How can I prevent this?

I've seen some website implements similar functionality. When a user send 3 messages and the website detected that those 3 messages are duplicates/similar. It warns the user against spamming.

Does anyone know of a function or script in PHP that I could use? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is to define the rule. For example, if you consider that you send three messages exactly, can be very easy to bypass the system.

One suggestion I had used for something like this - is this function http://php.net/similar_text

```
$var_1 = 'PHP IS GREAT';
$var_2 = 'WITH MYSQL';

similar_text($var_1, $var_2, $percent);

echo $percent;
// 27.272727272727

similar_text($var_2, $var_1, $percent);

echo $percent;
// 18.181818181818
```

Then check the user history, if the last 3 messages had 80% or more similar  you block the user.

Comment: +1 This is excellent. I would be curious to know the performance implications though :/ especially on longer text strings and as the user-base grows.

Comment: thanks for this. it seems to work smoothly. here's what i did. I encrypted the last message that the user sent and store it in a cookie. when a user send a message, it will be compared to the last one. if the percentage of similarity is above 60. it will record the number of instances in an encrypted cookie. after 3 identical message. the user will be banned for an hour or so. i believe that it will not affect the performance of my website since it does not require extra query. and i think there is no security issues here since the cookie is merely used in comparing. what do you think?

Comment: is 60% enough to consider a string similar? or should i raise it to 70%.

Comment: You need try - in my case I have defined 80% as limit. In the case of short strings, ie, you can get a higger rate than large.

Comment: yes i agree. that's why i put a condition that only message with more than 100 char will be compared.